# Global array print in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to print an array in python this way:

```
ord = []
def printTest():
    global ord
    print ', '.join(ord)


def main():
    ord = ["a","b"]
    printTest()

main()
```

But it prints only a new line empty. How can I solve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: You are not calling `printTruthTable` !

Comment: Usage of global variables is a bad idea in general. See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad if you interested in that idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `global ord` in the main method.

Comment: I already correct my answer. Sorry, I forget the call of the method.

Comment: The global ord in the main method solve this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `global` for main function:

```
def printTruthTable():
    print ', '.join(ord)


def main():
    global ord
    ord = ["a","b"]

main()
printTruthTable()
```

But good practice looks like this:

```
def TruthTable(ord):
    return ', '.join(ord)

def main():
    # some code
    return ["a","b"]

print TruthTable(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

`global` means that future **assignments** to this variable will be in the global scope.  When you just use `ord` in `printTruthTable()`, you don't need to say `global` because the global scope is already checked when you refer to a variable.  When you *assign* `ord`, however, you need to say that we are creating a global variable, not a local variable.  Therefore, move `global ord` from `printTruthTable()` to `main()`.  On the side, `ord` is a bad name because it shadows the built-in function.  Also, global variables are almost never needed.  In this case, just pass `ord` as an argument instead.